# Time Capsule & Encrypted Backups under OS X Lion

Tags: backup, encryption, time-machine, osx-lion, time-capsule

*How can I have an encrypted Time Machine backup on my Time Capsule?*

The option is in Time Machine preferences, but greyed out. Anyone know of hacks/workarounds to make this work?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[This gentleman](http://michaelnozbe.com/mac-osx-lion-secure-backup-to-time-capsule-wi) describes the process in full and he knows what he's talking about.

He uses a Time Capsule and 2 MacBook Airs for his setup.

Answer (score 0):

Encryption can only be done on a directly connected drive via USB, Firewire, or Thunderbolt port. Wireless drives, such as time capsule, are not supported for encryption.

Sources: [1](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20110721124750102) [2](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q1sKPtpLzng) and it was asked [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/19639/do-encrypted-time-machine-backups-work-across-a-network) on apple.stackexchange.

Comment: You can have encrypted backups and use a time capsule, but you'll need to create an encrypted sparse bundle file and copy it to the Time Capsule. See the link provided.